# Exporting BASH_XTRACEFD has no effect on subprocesses and it loses its special meaning

Tags: bash

I have just noticed that exporting this converts it into an ordinary variable with no special meaning in subshells.  Is this a security feature of bash?

Answer (score 2):

This is a snippet to check the feature:

```
#! /bin/bash

exec 3>| trace.txt

BASH_XTRACEFD=3
set -x

# Something to trace
i=1 ; test "$i" -gt 2

# Now in a subshell
(i=2 ; test "$i" -gt 2)

# Let's export it
export BASH_XTRACEFD

# Again check trace
i=3 ; test "$i" -gt 2

# Now in a subshell
(i=4 ; test "$i" -gt 2)
```

And here is `trace.txt`:

```
+ i=1
+ test 1 -gt 2
+ i=2
+ test 2 -gt 2
+ export BASH_XTRACEFD
+ i=3
+ test 3 -gt 2
+ i=4
+ test 4 -gt 2
```

It works! May be we have different bash version. Mine is `4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. What's yours?

Comment: 4.1.3.  I'm tied to the CentOS 6 distribution version, so can't use features from newer versions unfortunately.  Shame this doesn't work in my version.

Comment: I just tried and I get the exact same `trace.txt` on CentOS6 with bash 4.1 as Edouard with bash 4.3. The `BASH_XTRACEFD` variable appeared in bash 4.1 [[1](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars)] so it's supported on CentOS6. Craig, what is exactly not working?

Comment: I can't remember exactly what I was doing here, but for immediate subshells (the kind demonstrated in this script), it's not a problem.  The problem (if I recall correctly) was that I couldn't invoke `bash -x` with the file descriptor exported by the parent.  So equivalent to doing: `3>trace.txt BASH_XTRACEFD=3 bash -xc 'i=1 ; test "$i" -gt 2'`

Edit: so the problem is if you call one script from another.  The only way around it is to: `( source /path/to/my/other/script.sh )`